# Твердый знак или мягкий знак в слове "бьём" / "бъём"?

Tags: грамматика, правописание

Как правильно пишется слово 'б**Ь**ем' или 'б**Ъ**ем' - с мягким знаком или c твердым знаком?

- Я нашел некоторые ненадежные подтверждения в силу использования ['Ь'](https://znanija.com/task/11892617), 
  но словарь T9 на телефоне постоянно норовит исправить слово на 'б**Ъ**ем'.

---

Вопрос:

Как правильно пишется слово 'б**Ь**ем' или 'б**Ъ**ем'? И дайте, пожалуйста, подтверждения более твердые, нежели просто слова (ссылка на источник). В английском это мог быть Oxford dictionary, в русском может Даль, но не уверен.

Comment: У Даля в статье "бить" есть "бьёмся" и "бьёт". http://slovardalja.net/word.php?wordid=1858

Comment: You shouldn't use T9 (or any other text prediction/correction tool) as a reference. Its vocabulary can contain incorrect spellings (IDK why, but it happens).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мягкий знак однозначно: *бьём*. Твердый пишется в основном после приставок (*объём*).

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x

Comment: Может быть соит добавить в ответ  выписку из орфографического словаря, который на Грамоте.ру, и рекомендацию искать слова по форме инфинитива?